# "Far from" Vs "Far away"

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I was wondering what is the difference between the following sentences:

> 1- This building is near here and that building is **far from here**.
>
> 2- This building is near here and that building is **far away**.

To me they both mean the same.

Answer (score 2):

"Far *from*..[x]" states a relative position from which you are measuring the distance. "Far away" presumes you are speaking relative to your present location.

Of course, if you say "far from *here*", in in certain contexts that could mean the same as "far away" - for example, if you were speaking face-to-face with someone, your present location is the same, so ultimately the meaning of both statements is the same.

Imagine, though, that you were speaking on the telephone with somebody in a different location. Or, you were speaking with someone who noramlly lives in a different location:

> -"The city is far away".
>   -"Not from me".

In this context, the statement "the city is far away" is only true for one party, whereas "the city is far away *from here*" would be always true, as you have stated that it is relative to your location.

Comment: But @Astralbee I don't know why, but "far away" means something much farther from "far away". I wonder of it sounds the same to you.

Comment: "It is far" and "it is far away" mean the same to me, as do "it's *not* far" and "it's *not* far away". I don't know why you would think one sounds further. Perhaps you are relating it to stories that begin "in a land/galaxy *far, far away*" which try to give the impression of an immeasurable or unimaginable distance? But in everyday speech, I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: Well @Astralbee as you mentioned I can say: "This building is near here and that building is **far from here**" which  means the same as: "This building is near here and that building is **far away from here**." Right?